# Geocomplete to XML

Tags: php, xml, forms, geolocation

I am trying to insert/submit the form data to XML but it is not saving anything into the XML file.. currently only sending the **Latitude** line to get it to work.

I've been working off the GitHub Geocomplete form scripts and attempting to add a send data to XML script but i can't see what is missing?

INDEX.PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>$.geocomplete()</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      form { width: 300px; float: left; }
      fieldset { width: 320px; margin-top: 20px}
      fieldset strong { display: block; margin: 0.5em 0 0em; }
      fieldset input { width: 95%; }

      ul span { color: #999; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

<?php
    $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmldoc->load('sample.xml', LIBXML_NOBLANKS);

    $latitude = $xmldoc->firstChild->firstChild;
    if($latitude!=null){
        while($latitude!=null){
            echo $latitude->textContent.'<br/>';
            $latitude = $latitude->nextSibling;
        }
    }
?>

    <div class="map_canvas"></div>

    <form name='input' action='insert.php' method='post'>
      <input id="geocomplete" type="text" placeholder="Type in an address" value="Empire State Bldg" />
      <input id="find" type="button" value="find" />

      <fieldset>
        <h3>Address-Details</h3>


        <label>Latitude</label>
        <input name="latitude" type="text" value="">

        <label>Longitude</label>
        <input name="lng" type="text" value="">

        <label>Formatted Address</label>
        <input name="formatted_address" type="text" value="">

        <label>Locality</label>
        <input name="locality" type="text" value="">

      </fieldset>

<input type='submit' value='send'/>
    </form>






    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API KEY sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="findlocation/jquery.geocomplete.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(function(){
        $("#geocomplete").geocomplete({
          map: ".map_canvas",
          details: "form",
          types: ["geocode", "establishment"],
        });

        $("#find").click(function(){
          $("#geocomplete").trigger("geocode");
        });
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

INSERT.PHP

```
<?php
    header('Location:index.php');
    $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmldoc->load('sample.xml');

    $newAct = $_POST['latitude'];

    $root = $xmldoc->firstChild;

    $newElement = $xmldoc->createElement('latitude');
    $root->appendChild($newElement);
    $newText = $xmldoc->createTextNode($newAct);
    $newElement->appendChild($newText);

    $xmldoc->save('sample.xml');
?>
```

SAMPLE.XML

```
<list>
    <latitude></latitude>
<list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with the code you had, so I'll post the code and comments in the code should help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>$.geocomplete()</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
form {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}

fieldset {
    width: 320px;
    margin-top: 20px
}

fieldset strong {
    display: block;
    margin: 0.5em 0 0em;
}

fieldset input {
    width: 95%;
}

ul span {
    color: #999;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument ();
$xmldoc->load ( 'sample.xml', LIBXML_NOBLANKS );
// Fetch the latitude - using getElementsByTagName is a quick way of getting the
// data for a known element
$latitude = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName ( 'latitude' ) [0]->nodeValue;
?>

    <div class="map_canvas"></div>

    <form name='input' action='insert.php' method='post'>
        <input id="geocomplete" type="text" placeholder="Type in an address"
            value="Empire State Bldg" /> <input id="find" type="button"
            value="find" />

        <fieldset>
            <h3>Address-Details</h3>
            <label>Latitude</label> 
            <input name="latitude" type="text"
                value="<?php echo $latitude; ?>"> 
            <label>Longitude</label> 
            <input
                name="lng" type="text" value=""> 
            <label>Formatted Address</label> 
            <input
                name="formatted_address" type="text" value=""> 
            <label>Locality</label>
            <input name="locality" type="text" value="">
        </fieldset>
        <input type='submit' value='send' />
    </form>
    <script
        src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API KEY sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>
    <script
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="findlocation/jquery.geocomplete.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(function(){
        $("#geocomplete").geocomplete({
          map: ".map_canvas",
          details: "form",
          types: ["geocode", "establishment"],
        });

        $("#find").click(function(){
          $("#geocomplete").trigger("geocode");
        });
      });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

insert.php
As your XML already contained the latitude element, there was no need to create a new one.

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['latitude']) ){
    $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmldoc->load('sample.xml');

    // Fetch node to update (use [0] sd getElementsByTagName returns
    // an array of matching nodes)
    $latitude = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('latitude')[0];
    // Set node value
    $latitude->nodeValue = $_POST['latitude'];
    $xmldoc->save('sample.xml');

}

// Now the data is processed, redirect to main page
header('Location:index.php');
```

sample.xml
(Note that your close list element was  and not

```
<list>
    <latitude></latitude>
</list>
```